# Problems with the END enum when debugging with GCC ARM

Tags: android, c++, marmalade

I have an app which uses the `Tween` method for a number of animations. One of the tweens is the following:

```
pipe_Tweener.Tween(3.2f,
    FLOAT, &pSprite->m_X, (float) -pSprite->GetImage()->GetWidth(),
    FLOAT, &pSprite->m_Y, (float) pSprite->m_Y,
    FLOAT, &pSprite->m_X, (float) -pSprite->GetImage()->GetWidth(),
    FLOAT, &pSprite->m_Y, (float) pSprite->m_Y,
    ONCOMPLETE, &Game::ResetP,
    END);
```

and another is:

```
pipe_Tweener.Tween(JUMP_TIME,
    FLOAT, &bSprite->m_X, (float) bSprite->m_X,
    FLOAT, &bSprite->m_Y, (float) bSprite->m_Y-JUMP_HEIGHT,
    EASING, Ease::sineOut,
    ONCOMPLETE, &Game::EndAnimating, 
    END);
```

These tweens seem to work fine when debugging using the x86 debug. However when I use the GCC ARM debug I end up with an IwAssert failure at line 360 in `IwTween.cpp`.
I've debugged through the `Tween` method, and what I've noticed is that for my first tween everything is fine, I can see the method going through each `Type` (`FLOAT`, `FLOAT`, `FLOAT`, `FLOAT` , `ONCOMPLETE`, `END`). However for the second tween when the `Tween` method gets to the `END` enum,  `Type` becomes 0, (so I see for `Type` (`FLOAT`, `FLOAT`, `EASING`, `ONCOMPLETE`, `0`) causing the default case statement to execute, which calls the assert failure.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug with Marmalade itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually solved this, but I'll post in case it'll help anyone else.
My `EndAnimating` method was not static, which was causing some problem in the `Tween` method. Strangely it only caused a problem when debugging with the ARM simulator.